# UWP app -Invalid package family name, after update certificate

Tags: certificate, uwp, windows-10, windows-store, windows-dev-center

I created app for uwp (win 10 desktop). I could not build package for store. I received an error: it is necessary to update the certificate. I have updated certificate and build my package. But when I upload the package to the store, I get the error:

```
Invalid package family name: MyPackage.xxxx_xxxx (expected: MyPackage.yyyy_yyyyy)
Invalid package publisher name: CN=XYX (expected: CN=xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx)
```

But I opened my app manifest and I see:

```
Published: CN=xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx
Package Family Name: MyPackage.yyyy_yyyyy
```

It is what expected. In "open sertificate"  I see : Publisher -XYX.

How do I fix it all? Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I solved this issue. I made a mistake when creating new certificate. 
It must be so:

1. Open Package.appxmanifest.
2. Go to the "Packaging" tab.
3. Copy Publisher DN(number after CN=)
4. Click the button "Choose Certificate" and select the item "Create test certificate..."
5. **Copy the publisher DN from step 3 to the first editable text field**

Comment: In my case, i had to copy the Publisher (The part after "CN=") for this to work. With the DN, it was still changing my package family name.

Comment: I'm on 2019 Preview and I don't see "Create Test Certificate" option.

Comment: I haven’t been involved in UWP for several years. during this time, much could change

Comment: This post helped me, but I also had to right click on my project, and choose Store->Associate App with Store (even though I had done this previously) to get this working.

Answer (score 21):

## Update for Visual Studio 2019

1. Open Package.appxmanifest from Solution Explorer
2. Go to "Packaging" tab
3. Copy Publisher name after CN=. Looks like a GUID
4. Click "Choose Certificate..."
5. Click "Configure Certificate..."
6. Click "Create..."
7. Paste GUID from #3 into "Publisher Common Name"
8. Proceed to create and save certificate

Problem seems that it defaults to developer name instead of using the original GUID

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. I had to update a UWP app that used to publish just fine, but suddenly ran into these errors. The only change was building in 2019 and this work around fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

I found this MSDN blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamiedalton/2017/01/13/windows-store-error-updating-package-invalid-package-family-name/

The blog states that you should associate your App to the Store App using Visual Studio.

This seems to be the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This issue still exists even in Visual Studio 2022. I have been trying to complete my .net MAUI app and the "Store Association" has been my biggest headache and obstacle. No matter how many times i did the "Store Association" i could never get it to stay associated. All my problems for the last 6 weeks have been caused by the CN on the certificate being wrong.
And i didnt realize it until i decided to upload to the store to see if that would help and i got the error mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For us, the problem was that we tried to publish the app before associating it with a submission. The fix was the following:

1. Delete the temporary key .pfx file at the root of the directory
2. Re-associate the app with the store via the Publish menu