# How and where to correct data for a uwp app package to be submitted to the Microsoft Store?

Tags: uwp, package, store

My UWP app is ready to be submitted to the Microsoft Store. I created the package in Visual Studio and tried to submit to the store. Validation generated the error message below. Where and how can I correct this package data?

Invalid package family name: 6875WeCanAppsSoftware.WeCanSpeakPro_33cde44ccwfew (expected: 6875WeCanAppsSoftware.WeCanSpeakPro_g41babarqva5y)

Invalid package vendor name: CN=WeCanSpeak (expected: CN=8E59FA6F-E96D-4F39-ACA6-0D0D32F78F0B)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UWP app -Invalid package family name, after update certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951570/uwp-app-invalid-package-family-name-after-update-certificate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the current certificate is not valid, You can check whether the package family name in Partner Center is the same as that in Package.appxmanifest.

It is recommended to [associate the app with the store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#configure-a-package-with-the-manifest-designer). When you associate your app, some of the fields in the Packaging tab of the manifest designer are automatically updated.

1.Right-click your project name in Solution Explorer

2.Choose **Publish->Associate App** with the Store (before Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3, the Publish menu is named Store).

3.On the **select an app name** page, select the current project app.