Submitting UWP Package encounters an error: package family name and publisher name wrong
Invalid package family name: nnnnnpubname.appname_xxxidxxx (expected: nnnnnpubname.appname_yyyidyyy)
Invalid package publisher name: CN=name (expected: CN=xxxxGUIDxxxx)

I tried to upload an update on an UWP app of mine and got this error at https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/products/xxxPRIVATExxx/submissions/xxxPRIVATExxx/packages. I had to create a new local certificate in VS2023 as the old one had expired... The solution is associated with the store app.
What must I do to submit this to the store to make MSFT some commissions???

Similar to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/58648354/17316773, you need to check whether it is correctly associated with the store before packaging.

when you create a new certificate, assure that you use the same publisher as before. Meaning, use the publisher name you have associated with your developer account
